# How to manipulate how readr::type_convert handle columns with empty text?

Tags: r, type-conversion, readr

I would like to modfy the type_convert() function in readr package to set columns with empty variables to col_character() in stead of col_logical(). Any suggestions?

How it works:

```
str(readr::type_convert(data.frame(a = c("", ""), b = c("", "a"))))
# cols(
#  a = col_logical(),
#  b = col_character()
# )
#
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: logi  NA NA
#  $ b: chr  NA "a"
```

How I would like it to work:

```
str(readr::type_convert(data.frame(a = c("", ""), b = c("", "a")), some_tricky_setting))
# cols(
#  a = col_character(),
#  b = col_character()
# )
#
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: chr  NA NA
#  $ b: chr  NA "a"
```

Comment: This sounds like a XY-problem. Why do you need this? Do you specifically need to address this issue using the readr::type_convert-function? Or is it possible to convert to character somewhere else in the workflow (perhaps on importing the data?)

Comment: Well I am reading in data from xml-files, which may containt epmpty data i.e.. nodes where data was expected but empty. But yes I could perhaps drop these columns before type_convert as i likely do not need them later on.